# Big O Run Time for nested loops?

Tags: performance, algorithm, data-structures, runtime, big-o

How do you calculate the big O run-time efficiency for this code? My gut tells me it is O(n^3) but I'm not sure, as I'm not really sure if the loops are independent or dependent.

```
for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
    for (j=1; j<=n; j++)
        for (k=1; k<=n; k++)
          print ("%d %d %d/n", i, j, k);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your gut feeling is right.  You have three nested for loops iterating over n, so for each of the first n loops you make another n loops, each of which in turn make n more loops.  Thus O(n^3).

Edit:  think about how this will play out-
i is first 1, j 1 as well, and then k loops 1 through n.  Only after k has undergone that whole loop, will j increment to 2, then k undergoes the loop once again and so on.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, this function would be O(N^3) because inside each loop you are running N iterations.
 The loops are *not* independent, because they are **nested**.

N * N * N = N^3